# Can jdbc be used inside an onEdit trigger in a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to use jdbc inside an onEdit trigger?  I try the following code and it never reaches the last statement...

```
function onEdit(e) {
  cadena = e.range.getValue();

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('a2').setValue(new Date().toTimeString());  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('a1').setValue(cadena);  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('a3').setValue(new Date().toTimeString());  
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://<host>:3306/<database>", "<user>", "<pwd>");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('a4').setValue(new Date().toTimeString());  
}
```

I am using real strings for the database connection (not shown here).  The database connection works fine when executed from the script editor or from a custom function.  The database is a public database...

I cannot debug as it is a trigger.

Why is this happening?  Is it suppose to happen or is it an error?

R

Answer (score 0):

onEdit triggers don't have full access to the services, for security reasons. There are many that you can't use.

Take a look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237783/2048063).

Comment: Thanks for the tip...

It was here (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers) all of the time...

What I did not understand was that you could have "onEdit" triggers of both types of triggers: the simple ones and the Installable ones...

I just followed the instructions for the installable ones and it works perfectly.

Thanks

Comment: @Phil Bozak- thanks for the reference to my answer and congratulations to the new 'number one ' :-)