# Cant send email as action of onEdit() function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i want to send email every time there is change in the sheet. Im using this code:

```
        function onEdit(e) 
    {

      GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(), "Telegram Bot Update");

    }
```

but nothing happend!

when im using this code it does put a comment in the cells so - actually it works:

```
    function onEdit(e)
   {
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
   }
```

so where im wrong?

Comment: Change the name of `onEdit()` to something else.  `onEdit` is a "reserved function name."  When an edit is detected, apps script looks for an `onEdit` function, but an `onEdit` function is a "simple" trigger that has restricted permissions.  So, change the name, and "install" a trigger using the Edit menu and Current Projects triggers.

Comment: Thank for your reply! but it didnt work...i have noticed when im ruining this function manually - it does  send the email

Comment: As Sandy said, onEdit is a simple trigger that CAN NOT send emails or do anything that involves authorizations , create an installable trigger instead as specified [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App script onEdit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236783/google-app-script-onedit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)) recalls that the sendEmail method requires three parameters, namely `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)`. In your implementation of the onEdit function, you are only providing two parameters.

Make sure, you are providing a body (can also be an empty string) within the email you are sending.

Comment: Thank for your reply! i was adding the body but still it didnt work...i have noticed when im ruining this function manually - it does  send the email