# Trigger onEdit(e) does not trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

When I've tried just to `setValue("random")` to some cell with this trigger it does work, but when I've tried to execute this code(for returning certain sheet names from selected spreadsheet) it doesn't work! When I run that chunk of code as separate function it does work and return sheets normally.

So, why it doesn't execute part of code from "//RETURNING JUST BUILDING LIST" part when I change value in D2 cell?

```
function onEdit(e) {

var range = e.range;
var rangeEdit = e.range.getA1Notation();

if(rangeEdit == "D2"){

//RETURNING JUST BUILDING LIST  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

ss.getSheetsByName("OVERVIEW").getRange('A2').setValue("OK")

var sRNG = ss.getSheetByName("KEYS").getRange('A1:A12').getValues();

for (var z=0; z<sRNG.length; z++)
  if (sRNG[z][0] == ss.getSheetByName("OVERVIEW").getRange('G3').getValue()) {
  var xyz = z + 1;
  }

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var range = ss.getSheetByName("OVERVIEW").getRange(1, 8, 50, 1); 
 range.clear();

var shArray = [];
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

var spreadSheetsInA = 
SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ss.getSheetByName("KEYS").getRange('B' + xyz).getValue()).getSheets();

shArray = spreadSheetsInA.map(function(sheet) {
return [sheet.getName()];
});

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var range = ss.getSheetByName("OVERVIEW").getRange(1, 8, shArray.length, 1);
range.setValues(shArray);

var rDEL = 1
for (var xdel = 0; xdel<shArray.length; xdel++){
if(shArray[xdel][0].indexOf("Overview")>-1 | shArray[xdel][0].indexOf("Cashflow")>-1 | shArray[xdel][0].indexOf("Dates")>-1){
var delSHT = ss.getSheetByName("OVERVIEW");
delSHT.getRange('H' + rDEL).clear();

}
rDEL++
}  
}
}
```

Even when I've tried this, it doesn't work...

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var range = e.range;
  var rangeEdit = e.range.getA1Notation();
  if(rangeEdit == "D2"){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getSheetsByName("OVERVIEW").getRange("A2").setValue("ok")
}
}
```

Basically, I just need to execute code if value in D2 in sheet Overview is changed!

Comment: View>StackDriver Error > Uncheck all filters

Comment: TypeError: Cannot find function getSheetsByName in object Spreadsheet.

Comment: And still doesn't do anything... I'm not experienced with Sheets. As said, when it was as code without onEdit trigger it worked like a charm...

Comment: If you're not experienced, get experience. Start by seeing the Documentation. Is there a `getSheet`s`ByName()` in Class Spreadsheet ? Fix that. You'll keep on running  into errors, Search the documentation each time and fix it.

Comment: Thnx I will. I just didnt know why when using as separate function I dont have error and when using with trigger I do have error.

Comment: Your script tried to open a different spreadsheet, this is not allowed in simple triggers, see this post for details  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236783/google-app-script-onedit

Comment: @Sergeinsas thnx! On the end Ive figured out. Ive found exact same post :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App script onEdit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236783/google-app-script-onedit)