# E-mail alert on entering data to Google Spreadsheet not working

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I need the code that will send e-mail to some Google mail account whenever some data is entered to Google spreadsheet. I also need that data to be presented in e-mail, if possible.

I have found the answer for my question here [How to put a username to the cell , who made the last modification of the row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099951/how-to-put-a-username-to-the-cell-who-made-the-last-modification-of-the-row)

But this code for some reason do not work for me.

1 I open Google Spreadsheet script editor and paste that code

2 I change e-mail addresses to appropriate ones

3 I am asked for authorization

4 Then when I enter some data in Google spreadsheet I have display 
notification but no e-mail

Actually sometimes I received e-mail, but not always and I do not understand why it was working before, because I didn't change anything.

I tried to create new spreadsheet with a new code but there e-mail notifications are still not working.

I checked postini e-mail firewall and it's clear - no messages there and Spam folder is also clear.

There is absolutely no simple tutorials on the Web on how to send e-mail on data entering to Google spreadsheet, except the question here, which I posted on the beginning.

Here is the code that I used:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  r.setComment("Last modified: " + (new Date())+' by '+Session.getActiveUser());
  ss.toast('Dernière cellule modifiée = '+r.getA1Notation()+' par '+Session.getActiveUser());
}

function alert(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation()
      if(Session.getActiveUser()!='me@mymail.com'){
  MailApp.sendEmail('me@mymail.com', 'Modification dans le planning', 'la case '+cell+' du document a été modifiée par '+Session.getActiveUser());
} 
}
```

Thank you for your time and answers.

**EDIT**

After some more investigation I wrote this code. It send e-mail, but for some reason there is no user.id in e-mail, only cell.id.

```
function sendSimpleTextEmail() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
 var user = Session.getActiveUser();
 MailApp.sendEmail('me@mymail.com',user,cell);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to make it working

The code is:

```
function sendSimpleTextEmail() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
Logger.log(ss);
var name = ss.getName();
Logger.log(name);
var url = ss.getUrl();
Logger.log(url);
var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
Logger.log(cell);
var result = ss.getActiveCell().getValue();
Logger.log(result);
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
Logger.log(email);
MailApp.sendEmail('my@mymail.com','Data was changed in a spreadsheet `' +name+ '` in a cell ' +cell+ ' by user ' +email+ ' New Data=`' +result+ '`','Data was changed in a spreadsheet `' +name+ '` in a cell ' +cell+ ' by user ' +email+ ' New Data=`' +result+ '` Spreadsheet URL is ' +url);
}
```

After creating this script you need to configure manual triggers by pressing **Current project's triggers** button. You need only **On Edit** trigger.

**Remark1** - difference between On Change and On Edit triggers:
An installable edit trigger runs when a user modifies a value in a spreadsheet.
An installable change trigger runs when a user modifies the structure of a spreadsheet itself — for example, by adding a new sheet or removing a column. More info https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

**Remark2** - `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` works only inside GoogleApps domain. If I share spreadsheet with anybody outside of the domain - it will return empty string.

EDIT: typos

Comment: is it possible to get the previous value, means before edited value

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that well versed in Javascript, but just covering the obvious.

When you are testing your script, are you using an account OTHER than the one you've entered in the script in the changes?

I'm assuming you've changed me@mymail.com to your email?

```
if(Session.getActiveUser()!='me@mymail.com')
```

That part of the code says, If the user logged in ISNT this email, then send the mail judging by the next bit.

So when testing, use an account that isn't me@mymail.com

**EDIT**
Should have read the origianl posters question more.

So after reading properly the code.
unless I'm really mistaken, you should only have one on edit script ideally.

And the part of the script the OP wants isn't on the on edit trigger, it's just a function. The on edit part of the code simply adds comments to the sheet. So maybe a better answer for OP is to put the `alert()` function in the `onEdit()` function

Something like

```
function onEdit(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
      if(Session.getActiveUser()!='me@mymail.com'){
  MailApp.sendEmail('me@mymail.com', 'Modification dans le planning', 'la case '+cell+' du document a été modifiée par '+Session.getActiveUser());
}    
}
```

This is untested by the way, just hoping to help you get on track

Comment: Munkey, thank you for answer. I am completely lost now and am not sure that this code is what I need. I just need the code that will send e-mail whenever data in the cell is entered or edited. Answering your questions - yes, I changed the e-mail by another one.

Comment: Thank you for answer again. This code send user.id only if me@mymail.com is logged on, if other user is logged on it send e-mail but without user.id, who made a change in spreadsheet. I need to know who made a change in spreadsheet and also I need to have the data that was changed in the cell in e-mail. Really sorry for not clarifying it correctly for the first time. Now I see that the code that I found is far from what I need.

Comment: After doing a bit of reading, I'm not sure you can send emails when the trigger is onEdit.
Trying to think of a workaround.
Also, if you've shared you sheet as anyone with the link can view/edit, then they wouldn't need to login to edit. 
So there would be no username or email to send to yourself. just a thought

Comment: I finally made it working. Thank you for pointing to mistakes, which gave me motivation to work more on this subject.